# How to remove an element from a vector given the element?

Tags: rust

Is there a simple way to remove an element from a `Vec<T>`?

There's a method called [`remove()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.remove), and it takes an `index: usize`, but there isn't even an `index_of()` method that I can see.

I'm looking for something (hopefully) simple and O(n).

Answer (score 121, accepted):

This is what I have come up so far (that also makes the borrow checker happy):

```rust
let index = xs.iter().position(|x| *x == some_x).unwrap();
xs.remove(index);
```

I'm still waiting to find a better way to do this as this is pretty ugly.

Note: my code assumes the element does exist (hence the `.unwrap()`).

Comment: Note that the stdlib is still being designed, so it may lack some functions common in other languages. Feel free to submit a PR adding this!

Comment: After using rust for some time, removals are often done in index lists and so the filter/retain on indices is actually much cheaper than removing from the middle

Comment: Rust actually used to have a function that did exactly this, but then deprecated it https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.remove_item so i suppose they simply don't think it neccesary

Comment: @Kamil Tomšík That's an interesting-sounding comment. Are you talking about a situation where multiple elements are being removed? I see you didn't put in an answer and I'm not entirely clearly what you mean. Are `filter_map` and `collect` involved?

Comment: I suspect that this is not memory-efficient (with multiple items for removal), and that a solution not involving multiple manipulations of the heap is to be preferred. See my idea.

Answer (score 97):

You can use the [`retain` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain) but it will delete every instance of the value:

```
fn main() {
    let mut xs = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let some_x = 2;
    xs.retain(|&x| x != some_x);
    println!("{:?}", xs); // prints [1, 3]
}
```

Comment: The comparison made after the element is found are unnecessary

Comment: @malbarbo Yes, this is because this method removes every instance of the value.

Answer (score 76):

Your question is under-specified: do you want to return *all* items equal to your needle or just *one*? If one, the *first* or the *last*? And what if there is no single element equal to your needle? And can it be removed with the fast `swap_remove` or do you need the slower `remove`? To force programmers to think about those questions, there is no simple method to "remove an item" (see [this discussion](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/40062) for more information).

#### Remove *first* element equal to `needle`

```rust
// Panic if no such element is found
vec.remove(vec.iter().position(|x| *x == needle).expect("needle not found"));

// Ignore if no such element is found
if let Some(pos) = vec.iter().position(|x| *x == needle) {
    vec.remove(pos);
}
```

You can of course handle the `None` case however you like (panic and ignoring are not the only possibilities).

#### Remove *last* element equal to `needle`

Like the first element, but replace `position` with `rposition`.

#### Remove *all* elements equal to `needle`

```rust
vec.retain(|x| *x != needle);
```

#### ... or with `swap_remove`

Remember that `remove` has a runtime of O(n) as all elements after the index need to be shifted. `Vec::swap_remove` has a runtime of O(1) as it swaps the to-be-removed element with the last one. If the order of elements is not important in your case, use `swap_remove` instead of `remove`!

Answer (score 23):

There is a [`position()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.position) method for iterators which returns the index of the first element matching a predicate. Related question: [*Is there an equivalent of JavaScript's `indexOf` for Rust arrays?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482395/is-there-an-equivalent-of-javascripts-indexof-for-rust-arrays)

And a code example:

```
fn main() {
    let mut vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];

    println!("Before: {:?}", vec);

    let removed = vec.iter()
        .position(|&n| n > 2)
        .map(|e| vec.remove(e))
        .is_some();

    println!("Did we remove anything? {}", removed);

    println!("After: {:?}", vec);
}
```

Comment: This does not compile: `xs.remove(xs.iter().position(|x| *x == some_x).unwrap());` -- "cannot borrow `xs` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable"

Comment: @Kai Sellgren: Also known as: do not modify a container you are iterating on.

Answer (score 5):

**If your data is sorted**, please use binary search for `O(log n)` removal, which could be much much faster for large inputs.

```
match values.binary_search(value) {
  Ok(removal_index) => values.remove(removal_index),
  Err(_) => {} // value not contained.
}
```

Comment: The remove action is O(log n) anyway, so this solution isn't O(log n), even though the search part of it is.

Comment: In 99% of practical cases, the data structure you want in this situation is a HashSet. Then search and remove is O(1).

Comment: He just suggested to change the sequential search part for a binary search one if all set, which is a valid concern. So just tried to help, doesn't deserve a -1.

Answer (score 5):

Is [`extract_if()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.extract_if) new from the last answers?

Seems similar to Kai's answer:

```rust
#![feature(extract_if)]
let mut numbers = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15];

numbers.extract_if(|x| *x % 2 == 0).collect::<Vec<_>>();

assert_eq!(numbers, vec![1, 3, 5, 9, 11, 13, 15]);
```

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.extract_if

Comment: drain_filter: still  nightly-only and experimental.

Comment: Over 1 year later after @WolfgangKuehn still experimental. :-P

Comment: Use `extract_if()` only if you need the removed elements (in this case you don't access them). Use `retain()` otherwise. Also, why `.collect::<Vec<_>>()`?

Answer (score 1):

Since no one gave this solution:

```rust
pub trait RemoveElem<T> {
    fn remove_elem<F>(&mut self, predicate: F) -> Option<T>
    where
        F: Fn(&T) -> bool;
}

impl<T> RemoveElem<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn remove_elem<F>(&mut self, predicate: F) -> Option<T>
    where
        F: Fn(&T) -> bool,
    {
        self.iter()
            .position(predicate)
            .map(|index| self.remove(index))
    }
}
```

Like this, we can directly call the function on the vector:

```rust
let mut a1 = vec![1, 2, 1];
a1.remove_elem(|e| e == &1);
dbg!(&a1); // ouput: [ 2, 1 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

For a situation where you have multiple elements which you want removing, this works, is readable, and might be what Kamil Tomšík was talking about in his comment.

```
let mut my_vec : Vec<usize> = ... // for example, with usize elements
let numbers_to_be_deleted: Vec<usize> = ... 

... // put things into both Vecs

my_vec = my_vec.iter().filter_map(|val|{
    if numbers_to_be_deleted.contains(val) {
        return None
    }
    Some(*val)
}).collect();
```

This, naturally, does not assume ordering of the `usize`s in either `Vec`.

NB `my_vec` doesn't in fact need to be `mut`. If you instead do

```
let my_vec: Vec<_> = my_vec.iter().filter_map(|val|{ ...
```

...this works OK without a `mut`.

Kamil Tomšík says using a filter is "cheaper than removing from the middle". Anyone who's read The Book properly will have understood that this is precisely the sort of situation where you need to be conscious that good memory management can make a lot of difference. My solution doesn't appear to be using any heap at all (until the assignment after `collect()`), although I'm a Rust newb and don't know what's going on under the surface here. The whole [FilterMap](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.FilterMap.html) functionality is one of the more daunting parts of the standard library.

It'd be nice if someone were to take an interest in benchmarking for suggested solutions for both "ordered" and "unordered" scenarios.