# Is there an equivalent of JavaScript's indexOf for Rust arrays?

Tags: arrays, rust

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var index = fruits.indexOf("Apple");
```

```rust
let fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
let index = fruits.???
```

If there is no equivalent, maybe you can point me in the right direction? I found this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30558360), but it's for vectors, not arrays.

Comment: *it's for vectors, not arrays* — they are the same when it comes to iterating.

Comment: @Shepmaster is there (self).position_elem(&"Apple") for arrays? If not do you think you know how to make one? You can add it in the answers if you want.

Comment: There isn't *any* `position_elem` left in the standard library (I've added a comment to the accepted answer on the linked question). The other answer is still valid, and I've edited it to indicate it applies to any iterator.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the method [`position`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.position) on any iterator. You can get an iterator over an array with the [`iter()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter) method. Try it like this:

```
let fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
let res1 = fruits.iter().position(|&s| s == "Apple");
let res2 = fruits.iter().position(|&s| s == "Peter");

println!("{:?}", res1);    // outputs: Some(2)
println!("{:?}", res2);    // outputs: None
```

Comment: Rust is much verbose than Python and JavaScript.  ;)